# Sockets on a webhost

Tags: sockets, web, telnet, host

If you telnet to the ip address 192.43.244.18 port 13, you'll get the current time.
well, if I'm not wrong, this is simply a server socket. But there's one thing strange: how's this socket always listening? 
If I take a PHP page and program sockets in there, I still have to request for the page first in order to activate the server socket, but this one isn't associated with any pages, and even if a make a perl script, I still have to request for that in order to run the server socket!
My question is: how can I make such a thing - an always listening socket - on a webhost (any language will do)?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the process that's listening on the socket as a daemon (Linux) or service (Windows), or just a regular program really (although that's less elegant).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that webhosts usually don't have this capability since they're shared environment and what not.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know how can I run the program on the webhost as a service/daemon. The thing is, the IP address above doesn't even redirect to a webpage or webhost! I don't know what it is...

Comment: They just have a server of some kind, in this case it's a telnet server. Basically it's just a program that talks on some specific port with other programs.

Comment: @Anton but where can I find a telnet server??

Comment: I don't want it to be my own computer cause I don't want it to be turned on always! I'm looking for a web host of some kind.

Comment: Then you will have to get either a virtual host of some kind like what http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/ offers or get a dedicated server for your needs. I would suggest that you fiddle a little with this on your own computer at first to get a hang of how things works.

Answer (score 0):

A simple place to begin would be http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html which teaches you how to make a simple serversocket in Java that listens for a connection on a specific port. The program created will have to be run at all times to be able to accept the connections.

Comment: what about the webhosts? I can't run a Java program on a webhost because they don't support it.

Comment: Not much to do there, you could perhaps try having a php page where you have something like `while(true)` and then keep trying to access the page, dunno if that's a good solution though.